# Text extraction from table cells

Tags: pdf, itext

I have a pdf. The pdf contains a table. The table contains many cells (>100). I know the exact position (x,y) and dimension (w,h) of every cell of the table.
I need to extract text from cells using itextsharp. Using PdfReaderContentParser + FilteredTextRenderListener (using a code like this http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=279 ) I can extract text but I need to run the whole procedure for each cell. My pdf have many cells and the program needs too much time to run. Is there a way to extract text from a list of "rectangle"? I need to know the text of each rectangle.  I'm looking for something like PDFTextStripperByArea by PdfBox (you can define as many regions as you need and the get text using .getTextForRegion("region-name") ).

Answer (score 3):

This option is not immediately included in the iTextSharp distribution but it is easy to realize. In the following I use the iText (Java) class, interface, and method names because I am more at home with Java. They should easily be translatable into iTextSharp (C#) names.

If you use the `LocationTextExtractionStrategy`, you can can use its a posteriori `TextChunkFilter` mechanism instead of the a priori `FilteredRenderListener` mechanism used in the sample you linked to. This mechanism has been introduced in version 5.3.3.

For this you first parse the whole page content using the `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` without any `FilteredRenderListener` filtering applied. This makes the strategy object collect `TextChunk` objects for all PDF text objects on the page containing the associated base line segment.

Then you call the strategy's `getResultantText` overload with a `TextChunkFilter` argument (instead of the regular no-argument overload):

```
public String getResultantText(TextChunkFilter chunkFilter)
```

You call it with a different `TextChunkFilter` instance for each table cell. You have to implement this filter interface which is not too difficult as it only defines one method:

```
public static interface TextChunkFilter
{
    /**
     * @param textChunk the chunk to check
     * @return true if the chunk should be allowed
     */
    public boolean accept(TextChunk textChunk);
}
```

So the accept method of the filter for a given cell must test whether the text chunk in question is inside your cell.

(Instead of separate instances for each cell you can of course also create one instance whose parameters, i.e. cell coordinates, can be changed between `getResultantText` calls.)

**PS:** As mentioned by the OP, this `TextChunkFilter` has not yet been ported to iTextSharp. It should not be hard to do so, though, only one small interface and one method to add to the strategy.

**PPS:** In a comment [sschuberth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1127485/sschuberth) asked

> Do you then still call `PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage()` when using `getResultantText()`, or does it somehow replace that call? If so, how to you then specify the page to extract to?

Actually `PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage()` internally already uses the no-argument `getResultantText()` overload:

```
public static String getTextFromPage(PdfReader reader, int pageNumber, TextExtractionStrategy strategy, Map<String, ContentOperator> additionalContentOperators) throws IOException
{
    PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);
    return parser.processContent(pageNumber, strategy, additionalContentOperators).getResultantText();
}
```

To make use of a `TextChunkFilter` you could simply build a similar convenience method, e.g.

```
public static String getTextFromPage(PdfReader reader, int pageNumber, LocationTextExtractionStrategy strategy, Map<String, ContentOperator> additionalContentOperators, TextChunkFilter chunkFilter) throws IOException
{
    PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);
    return parser.processContent(pageNumber, strategy, additionalContentOperators).getResultantText(chunkFilter);
}
```

In the context at hand, though, in which we want to parse the page content only once and apply multiple filters, one for each cell, we might generalize this to:

```
public static List<String> getTextFromPage(PdfReader reader, int pageNumber, LocationTextExtractionStrategy strategy, Map<String, ContentOperator> additionalContentOperators, Iterable<TextChunkFilter> chunkFilters) throws IOException
{
    PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);
    parser.processContent(pageNumber, strategy, additionalContentOperators)

    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (TextChunkFilter chunkFilter : chunkFilters)
    {
        result.add(strategy).getResultantText(chunkFilter);
    }
    return result;
}
```

(You can make this look fancier by using Java 8 collection streaming instead of the old'fashioned `for` loop.)

Comment: C# version of LocationTextExtractionStrategy has not getResultantText(TextChunkFilter chunkFilter). :(  But your idea is interesting. I will look for a little different approach.

Comment: Oops, you are right. Interesting, as this feature has been publicly available in version 5.3.4 (not 5.3.3 as claimed in JavaDoc comments) of iText / Java which is more than a year old. But I think it should be really easy to translate into C#, only one interface and one method after all...

Comment: Do you then still call `PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage()` when using `getResultantText()`, or does it somehow replace that call? If so, how to you then specify the page to extract to?

Comment: @sschuberth Confer my PPS in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on how to extract text from a table-like structure in a PDF using itextsharp.  It returns a collection of rows and each row contains a collection of interpreted columns.  This may work for you on the premise that there is a gap between one column and the next which is greater than the average width of a single character.  I also added an option to check for wrapped text within a virtual column.  Your mileage may vary.

```
   using (PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(stream))
        {
            for (int page = 1; page <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++)
            {

                TableExtractionStrategy tableExtractionStrategy = new TableExtractionStrategy();
                string pageText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page, tableExtractionStrategy);
                var table = tableExtractionStrategy.GetTable();

            }
        }



        public class TableExtractionStrategy : LocationTextExtractionStrategy
        {
            public float NextCharacterThreshold { get; set; } = 1;
            public int NextLineLookAheadDepth { get; set; } = 500;
            public bool AccomodateWordWrapping { get; set; } = true;

            private List<TableTextChunk> Chunks { get; set; } = new List<TableTextChunk>();

            public override void RenderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo)
            {
                base.RenderText(renderInfo);
                string text = renderInfo.GetText();
                Vector bottomLeft = renderInfo.GetDescentLine().GetStartPoint();
                Vector topRight = renderInfo.GetAscentLine().GetEndPoint();
                Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(bottomLeft[Vector.I1], bottomLeft[Vector.I2], topRight[Vector.I1], topRight[Vector.I2]);
                Chunks.Add(new TableTextChunk(rectangle, text));
            }

            public List<List<string>> GetTable()
            {
                List<List<string>> lines = new List<List<string>>();
                List<string> currentLine = new List<string>();

                float? previousBottom = null;
                float? previousRight = null;

                StringBuilder currentString = new StringBuilder();

                // iterate through all chunks and evaluate 
                for (int i = 0; i < Chunks.Count; i++)
                {
                    TableTextChunk chunk = Chunks[i];

                    // determine if we are processing the same row based on defined space between subsequent chunks
                    if (previousBottom.HasValue && previousBottom == chunk.Rectangle.Bottom)
                    {
                        if (chunk.Rectangle.Left - previousRight > 1)
                        {
                            currentLine.Add(currentString.ToString());
                            currentString.Clear();
                        }
                        currentString.Append(chunk.Text);
                        previousRight = chunk.Rectangle.Right;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // if we are processing a new line let's check to see if this could be word wrapping behavior
                        bool isNewLine = true;
                        if (AccomodateWordWrapping)
                        {
                            int readAheadDepth = Math.Min(i + NextLineLookAheadDepth, Chunks.Count);
                            if (previousBottom.HasValue)
                                for (int j = i; j < readAheadDepth; j++)
                                {
                                    if (previousBottom == Chunks[j].Rectangle.Bottom)
                                    {
                                        isNewLine = false;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                        }

                        // if the text was not word wrapped let's treat this as a new table row
                        if (isNewLine)
                        {
                            if (currentString.Length > 0)
                                currentLine.Add(currentString.ToString());
                            currentString.Clear();

                            previousBottom = chunk.Rectangle.Bottom;
                            previousRight = chunk.Rectangle.Right;
                            currentString.Append(chunk.Text);

                            if (currentLine.Count > 0)
                                lines.Add(currentLine);

                            currentLine = new List<string>();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (chunk.Rectangle.Left - previousRight > 1)
                            {
                                currentLine.Add(currentString.ToString());
                                currentString.Clear();
                            }
                            currentString.Append(chunk.Text);
                            previousRight = chunk.Rectangle.Right;

                        }
                    }
                }

                return lines;
            }

            private struct TableTextChunk
            {
                public Rectangle Rectangle;
                public string Text;

                public TableTextChunk(Rectangle rect, string text)
                {
                    Rectangle = rect;
                    Text = text;
                }

                public override string ToString()
                {
                    return Text + " (" + Rectangle.Left + ", " + Rectangle.Bottom + ")";
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This strategy makes a number of assumptions (some of which Shaun already mentioned), so it is not usable for all kind of PDFs with tables. But for PDFs for which the assumptions are true, the table contents are extracted without the need to know coordinates.

Comment: Just curious -- is there a reference out there for more versatile parsing using iText?  I searched SE and couldn't find one -- very interested to know if there is something better with sample source.

Comment: Well, concerning text extraction iText offers you a framework in which you can develop extraction strategies of your choice of sophistication. But many users assume that the two sample strategies bundled with iText are all there is. You'll find some specialized extraction strategies and POCs for more advanced stuff e.g. here in stack overflow answers but not a big free solution like tabula. There may be some closed source text extractors based on iText somewhere out there.

Comment: @Shaun thanks a ton for this answer
This helped us out a lot!!